# Creating backup with sqlcmd in batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm attempting to create an automated backup of a database using this [guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se)

I've created a stored procedure in my master database called `sp_BackupDatabases` (as described in step 1) and I've created a `.bat` file with the following contents:

```
sqlcmd -U sa -S PCNAME -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\backups\', @databaseName='DBNAME', @backupType='F'"
```

The result is it is executing with no errors, but no backups are actually being created. Are there any additional guides for how to troubleshoot `sqlcmd` problems?

Comment: you mean outside of not usnig sqlcmd but calling the sp and the commands from ssms to debug them?

Comment: And what console output do you see in your batch file?  NB  you should set the `-b` switch so sqlcmd sets the ERRORLEVEL on failure.

Comment: I get a prompt to enter the db password. It accepts the correct pw, but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you checking the directory on the machine where your database server is running? Or are you checking the machine on which you are running sqlcmd? You specify a servername in your command so presumably you are not running this on the actual server itself.